# Refreshing issues in lightning:recordViewForm

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-record-form, lightning-recordviewform

I'm having **TestObject** as parent object and **New Custom Object** having M-D relationship to it. **TestObject** having Min and Max Rollup summary fields which will rollup number field in child object.

I was rendering parent information using **lightning:recordViewForm** with certain fields, if we perform any dml in child need to refresh the parent record information.

Here's my Markup code:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.showViewForm}">
    <lightning:recordViewForm recordId="a0G2800000KJxZp" objectApiName="TestObject__c">
            <lightning:layout class=" slds-wrap custom-layout">

                <lightning:layoutItem size="4" padding="around-small">
                    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Name" class="output-element"/>
                </lightning:layoutItem>
                <lightning:layoutItem size="4" padding="around-small">
                    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Max__c" class="output-element"/>
                </lightning:layoutItem>
                <lightning:layoutItem size="4" padding="around-small">
                    <lightning:outputField fieldName="Min__c" class="output-element"/>
                </lightning:layoutItem>
            </lightning:layout> 
    </lightning:recordViewForm>
</aura:if>
```

Whenever i was updating child records, i just need to refresh the parent details.

I tried with setting boolean variable false before making dml, after success callback making the boolean as true, but it didn't reflected.

Here's controller code:

```
update : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.set("v.showViewForm", false);
    var action = component.get("c.updateParentValues");
    action.setParams({
        'updateList': component.get("v.records")
    });
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set("v.showViewForm", true);
            component.set("v.records", response.getReturnValue());
        }

    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Here's my screen shots

After submitting:
[image]

After refreshing:
[image]

Upto my knowledge when we are rebuilding the dom using aura:if it should refresh.

Did i missed anything here (or) Is there any other alternative approaches to refresh the record view form.

I tried with **lightning:recordForm** as well.

Comment: Do you have two different components for parent and child records? And that you are making edits in child and expect to refresh parent?

Comment: Have you tried using force:refreshView? It's not the DOM that needs to be updated, it's the underlying data.

Comment: @JayantDas, No im having only one component, parent info will be rendered using record view form and child records are rendering in the table, when click on save im doing dml and tried to refresh the dom using aura:if.

Comment: @sfdcfox, I tried with force:refreshView 
**$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();** as well, but it also didn't worked, 
If we are doing the dom refresh means, respective data also need to refresh right?

Answer (score 0):

did you tried:

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.showViewForm == TRUE}">
```

I guess, the condition is also true, if you have defined some default value for v.showViewForm, because it checks if the attribute is set.

Let me know, if this helps

Greets,
Bernhard

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! I'm afraid that this doesn't really provide an answer to the question. This may be more appropriate as a comment. Once you gain enough reputation (50) you'll be able to add comments on other people's questions and answers. Please read [answer]. As a final note, explicitly checking `<boolean variable> == true` can be simplified to simply `<boolean variable>`, which is what OP (**O**riginal **P**oster of the question) currently has.

Comment: Thanks Derek!

Yeah, I had no other choice - it was more a suggestion then an answer!

Thats true, but it would be also false if the attribute is null or undefined - on which I wanted to point out.
Greets